# How to fix ValueError: axes don't match array when loading weights after saving weights with callbacks.ModelCheckpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I had to train a model for 2000 epochs and save a checkpoint (only the weights) at each epoch. For saving I uses the following Callback:

```
mc = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpoints_path, save_weights_only=True, save_freq=1)
```

Now I need to load each of the checkpoints and get predictions, and for that I use the following code:

```
model = get_model()
model.load_weights(check_path)# This produces the error
```

When I try to load the weights I get the following error:

> Exception has occurred: ValueError axes don't match array

I already search in other questions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779022/valueerror-axes-dont-match-array-when-loading-previously-saved-model) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779022/valueerror-axes-dont-match-array-when-loading-previously-saved-model)), but in these cases they propose to freeze the model before saving the weights, but I can't do that because the models are being saved by the ModelCheckpoint callback.

If there's a solution that requires only a change in the loading it would be better, so that I don't have to train again the model for so many epochs and time.

Comment: How did you define the function `get_model()`?

Comment: Btw. you should set the parameter `save_freq='epoch'` if you want to save the weights at the end of each epoch. Currently the callback saves the weights after each batch.

Comment: Thanks, but my batch/epoch is one file.

Comment: @MrT77 did you manage to solve this? I am coming across the same issue but all other fixes aren't working